# Hadoop streaming with Python: Keeping track of line numbers

Tags: python, hadoop, position, streaming, line-numbers

I am trying to do what should be a simple task: I need to convert a text file to upper case using Hadoop streaming with Python.

I want to do it by using the [TextInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html) which passes file position keys and text values to the mappers.  The problem is that Hadoop streaming [automatically discards the file position keys](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html#N1019C), which are needed to preserve the ordering of the document.

How can I retain the file position information of the input to the mappers?  Or is there a better way to convert a document to upper case using Hadoop streaming?

Thank you.

Comment: How big is the file - do you need to use multiple mappers for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your job is just to upper case a single file, then Hadoop isn't really going to give you anything that streaming the file to a single machine, performing the upper case and then writing the contents back up to HDFS. Even with a huge file (say 1TB), you are still going to need to get everything to a single reducer such that when it is written back to HDFS it's stored in a single contiguous file.

In this case i would configure your streaming job to have a single mapper per file (set the split min and max size to something huge, larger than the file itself), and run a map only job.