# Hadoop Streaming with TextInputFormat and Python - keep track of line number

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to compute the sum for every diagonal on a square matrix. I'm using Python and Hadoop streaming but I can't find any way to configure Hadoop streaming to get the offset for each line as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903987/what-are-the-main-differences-between-keyvaluetextinputformat-and-textinputforma) says, using `TextInputFormat`.

There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303448/hadoop-streaming-with-python-keeping-track-of-line-numbers) on StackOverflow asking the same thing, but there's no response on how to do it.
And the [hadoop doc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#N1019C) says something about discarding `keys of LongWritable class` but I'm not sure if that's the offset.

How can I configure the job to get the offset?
Do I need to make a new class derived from `TextInputFormat` and not return `LongWritable`? How do I do that if I don't know Java? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some more research on StackOverflow and there's another guy asking the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600495/hadoop-streaming-mapper-byte-offset-not-being-generated) but no one answered although he does say that using `-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat` works, but it takes a lot of time for the job to complete.

I know there could be a much better answer to this, but till someone answers, this is good enough.